# How to scrape a web page using python for numbers from 1 to 500 that maybe present on the page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation

I have been looking to make a program for scraping a webpage to see if it contains any number from 1 to 500, I found many ways to this on the internet, but the thing is all of them open a new webpage in the beginning, I dont want that to happen but for it to switch to a tab that I have already opened. Is there any code that will switch to a tab on a webpage that I have already opened, then execute a list of commands(basic clicking stuff), and finally scrape the webpage for numbers from 1 to 500?

Comment: The type of behavior you want is possible by writing a browser extension/plugin. But that being said, I advise the use of actual programs intended for web automation such as Selenium or Playwright.

Comment: Is what i want possible through selenium?

Comment: Yes. Look into Selenium IDE. https://www.selenium.dev/